# to_date is not returning data

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query which is not returning any data because of below condition

```
where  fcc_cust_addr_evnt.MIS_DATE = to_date(? , 'MM/DD/YYYY').
```

data is stored like this DD-MON-YYYY format in the table in MIS_DATE column.

How can I achieve the expected result .

Comment: What is `?`? What is the datatype of `MIS_DATE`? How is this related to PL/SQL or SQL Developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, dates have a time component.  So, it is possible that `MIS_DATE` has a time component, so `=` does not work.

If that is the case, then logic such as this will work:

```
where trunc(fcc_cust_addr_evnt.MIS_DATE) = to_date(? , 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

The `trunc()` function removes the time component.

Answer (score 0):

Using `trunc()` will prevent an index on that column being used; you could add a function-based index if that's something you might need to do a lot. But if there is an index and you want to keep using it then you can look for a range instead:

```
where fcc_cust_addr_evnt.MIS_DATE >= to_date(? , 'MM/DD/YYYY')
and fcc_cust_addr_evnt.MIS_DATE < to_date(? , 'MM/DD/YYYY') + 1
```

which will find all times from midnight on that day, up to but not including midnight the following day. That pattern works for timestamps too.

If you don't want to pass the value twice - with two bind placeholders - you could add a CTE that has one and then refer to the value from that CTE in the main query.

It's also usually better to bind actual dates if you have them in your application, rather than converting to a string to pass in and then converting back to a date; but that depends on the data type you application is holding.